# Count and reshape on each distinct variable

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I have a data frame with two columns, `date` and `id`

```
> test
         date id
1  2018-01-01  a
2  2018-01-02  b
3  2018-01-03  c
4  2018-01-04  d
5  2018-01-01  e
6  2018-01-02  f
7  2018-01-03  a
8  2018-01-04  b
9  2018-01-01  c
10 2018-01-01  d
11 2018-01-01  d
```

My goal is to shape this into a table that counts the number of each occurrence of each distinct `id` (in the dataset) per date, while preserving 0s if there is no occurrence of an `id` on a particular date using `dplyr` or `data.table`

The desired result output would look something like this:

```
> output
        date a b c d e f
1 2018-01-01 1 0 1 2 1 0
2 2018-01-02 0 1 0 0 0 1
3 2018-01-03 1 0 1 0 0 0
4 2018-01-04 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

This code does not produce the desired result:

```
 test  %>%
     group_by(date, id) %>%
     summarise_all(funs(sum))
```

What is the correct way to produce the desired output using `dplyr` or `data.table`?

Below is a copy of the sample data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(date = structure(c(17532, 17533, 17534, 17535, 
17532, 17533, 17534, 17535, 17532, 17532, 17532), class = "Date"), 
    id = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c", "d", 
    "d")), .Names = c("date", "id"), row.names = c(NA, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: isn't this just `table(test$date, test$id)` ? OR just `table(test)` ? Do you need answer specifically in `dplyr` or `data.table` only?

Comment: yes that works!